# Java File.listFiles() shows more files than Windows dir

Tags: java, windows

I tried to create some files in Java, and for some reason they didn't actually get created according to Windows. When I use File.listFiles() on the directory, they show up, but they don't show up in the Windows command prompt when I use dir, nor do they show up in the file explorer. This is the output from a piece of Java code I wrote to find all the files in the directory, and then from dir:

[image]

And in case anyone is curious, here's the java code:

```
import java.io.File;


public class DoesFileExist{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File dir = new File("C:\\directory\\path\\testing trie");

        File[] list = dir.listFiles();
        System.out.printf("%-80s %-10s %-5s\n", "filename", "isArray()", "size");
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%-80.80s %-10s %-5d\n", list[i].toString(), list[i].isFile(), list[i].length());
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why Java can see these files, but Windows can't?

EDIT:
The command shown  is just dir, but dir /A and dir *.* show the same result
Also, isArray() in the formatted display of the results from Java should have been "isFile()".

Comment: Perhaps some of the files are hidden? Try running `dir /A` and see if there are still differences.

Comment: You didn't show your `dir` command, and I suspect you ran `dir *.*`.

Comment: @chrylis I do show the dir command, but it was just dir in this screenshot. Question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. If you have Comodo on your system, check a hidden folder called VTRoot, your files are in there. Then remove Comodo and choose a different antivirus.